# Нужно вывести данные из двухтаблиц бд Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть таблица shop, в которой хранятся товары, как вывести из другой таблицы размеры к этим товарам? Запрос надо во view делать, или можно как-то через контроллер?

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Shop::find()->where(['status'=>1])->orderBy('price'),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее всего будет связать модели этих двух таблиц через связи `hasOne` или `hasMany`, и получать доступ к размерам непосредственно из экземпляра модели `shop`. [Про связи](http://skill.vpvd.ru/hasone-hasmany-svyazannye-dannye-v-yii2.html)

Answer (score 1):

До конца не раскрыт вопрос. Если я правильно тебя понял тебе нужно еще один столбец в твоем GridView с соответствующими данными из другой таблицы?
Что касается запроса то его лучше делать в модели. А из контроллера запрашивать нужные данные и передавать их во view.
Предположим у тебя есть модель ShopSearchс полями id, category_id, и тд, так же есть модель Category с полями id, name. Чтоб в GridView можно было вывести Category->name с фильтром и поиском по имени а не по id. То нужно сделать слудущее:
В модели ShopSearchдобавляете свойство category_name в функции rules пишитем ему ограничения примерно чтото подобное ['category_name', 'string', 'max' => 20] в зависимости от ситуации, и используете эту переменную как источник данных от GridView

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Shop::find()->Join('category', 'id = category.category_id');

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            '....'
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->category_name])
              ->....;

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

А в GridView просто используете новое добавленное поле category_name.

```
GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filterModel' => $searchModel,
   'tableOptions' => [
       'class' => 'table table-hover'
    ],
    'columns' => [
         ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
         id,
         category_name,
         ....,             
    ]
]);
```

И уже в контроллере

```
actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new ShopSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $this->render('index', ['searchModel' => $searchModel, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
}
```

Что дает этот подход?
Поиск, и фильтр... без каких либо замыканий и колбеков. 
Примерно как-то так из коробки, если я правильно опнял задачу